# Grails 2.3.8 app is not rendering template from plugin in production mode

Tags: templates, grails

I have a plugin structured Grails application contains lot of plugins. from main application gsp page, I am trying to call `<g:render template ...../>` syntax to render template which exists in plugin. It works fine in dev mode and qa mode. But its not working in prod mode, when I deployed into WebLogic and try to run the app, I am getting following error.

syntax I used to render template is `<g:render plugin="applicationFramework" template="/common/onLoadPageErrorHandler"/>`

```
GrailsTagException occurred when processing request: [GET] /customerSearch/showCustomerSearchPage
Template not found for name [/common/onLoadPageErrorHandler] and path [/common/_onLoadPageErrorHandler.gsp]. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template not found for name [/common/onLoadPageErrorHandler] and path [/common/_onLoadPageErrorHandler.gsp]
```

but when I give like below..
`<g:render plugin="ApplicationFramework" template="/common/onLoadPageErrorHandler"/>`,
Then its working fine. but its not working in dev mode (from IntelliJ IDE).

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin name is camel-cased you need to refer to the plugin with dashes between the words like you do for the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
<g:render template='/common/onLoadPageErrorHandler'
          plugin='application-framework' />
```

Comment: Try upgrading to 2.3.11 or 2.4.4